# How to get the node value in the ValidationEventHandler of JAXB while unmarshalling?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

How can I get the node details in the **ValidationEventHandler** in JAXB when an exception occurs while Unmarshalling?

```
My code:

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.piyush");
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new File("D:/liferay-develop/workspace/cat_test/v1/STD_MP.xsd")));
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    ValidationEventCollector validationCollector= new ValidationEventCollector();
    jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler( validationCollector );
    STDMP ts = (STDMP)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml_gkuzu);
    if(validationCollector.hasEvents())
    {
        for(ValidationEvent event:validationCollector.getEvents())
        {
            String msg = event.getMessage();
            System.out.println(msg);
            // How to get the node details here ? I'm getting null value for node.
        }
```